# why tap device transmit icmpv6 ping request use the first ipv6 show in tap device?

Tags: c, linux, centos7, tap, icmpv6

I am opening a TAP device at centos 7, it has the IPv6 addresses `fec0::a:1/64` and `2408:8160:a100:2::2`. It has the route `3000::/64` via `fec0::a:2`.

I need to ping `3000::1` at host, use C program to reply neighbor advertisement, wireshark capture packet as follows:

[image]

The TAP device uses `2408:8160:a100:2::2` as source IP to send an ICMPv6 ping request.

I find that when I use "IP a" to show infomation of the TAP, `2408:8160:a100:2::1` is in front of `fec0::a:1/64`, so the source IP is `2408:8160:a100:2::2`; if I add `fec0::b:1/64` to TAP device, `fec0::b:1/64` is in front of `fec0::a:1`, it will use `fec0::b:1/64` as source IP.

"ip a" result as following:
[[image]

if the TAP only has one IPv6 address `fec0::a:1`, the source IP will be `fec0::a:1`.

So how can I use `fec0::a:1` as source IP forever when tap device has other IPv6 address?

Comment: It should never prefer a site-local address over a global (routable) address.

Comment: I doubt that routing between scopes (e.g. from site-local to global) is a good idea - unless NAT is used: (Even if this is the case in your network) It is not guaranteed that `3000::1` is not inside another network that also uses site-local addresses. The echo reply would be sent to another computer that also has the address `fec0::a:1`. For this reason, I could even imagine that `3000::1` detects the IP packet as "invalid packet".

Comment: yes, global address has higher priority, however what I really concerned is that the source IP will always be the first IP which uses "ip a" to show.  The source IP should be `fec0::a:1` which I really want.

Comment: According to the RFCs, the source address with the same "label" shall be selected if available. You can see the "labels" on a Linux machine using the `ip addrlabels` command. If you `ping` machine `fcc0::b:c`, `fcc0::a:1` will be used as source address; if you ping `3000::1`, `2408:8160:a100:2::2` will be used as source address!